# SQL query not returning the criteria set

Tags: mysql, sql, criteria, where-clause

I am developing a flowerbed planting system, and have written an SQL statement which queries 8 tables in order to return a list of suitable plants.

**Table structure:** http://pastebin.com/0DUYQis1 [outputted from phpmyadmin]

**Example Data:** http://gyazo.com/13dad0b3370b5053dbcad2a32013a54a / http://gyazo.com/1bd313adb3e8ccd01354c979e69fd059

**SQL Statement:**

```
SELECT Plant.Plant_ID, Plant.Plant_Quantity, Plant.Plant_Price, Plant.Plant_Description, Plant.Plant_Latin_Name, Plant.Plant_Common_Name, Plant.Plant_Height, Plant.Plant_Spread, Plant.Plant_Type, Plant.Plant_Family, Plant.Plant_Picture, Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect, Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Flower_Colour, Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season, Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Foliage_Colour, Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season, Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture, Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH, Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type, Plant_Sun_Type.Plant_Sun_Type 

FROM Plant 

INNER JOIN Plant_Aspect ON Plant.Plant_ID = Plant_Aspect.Plant_ID 
INNER JOIN Plant_Flower_Colour ON Plant.Plant_ID = Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_ID 
INNER JOIN Plant_Foliage_Colour ON Plant.Plant_ID = Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_ID 
INNER JOIN Plant_Moisture ON Plant.Plant_ID = Plant_Moisture.Plant_ID
INNER JOIN Plant_Soil_PH ON Plant.Plant_ID = Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_ID 
INNER JOIN Plant_Soil_Type ON Plant.Plant_ID = Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_ID 
INNER JOIN Plant_Sun_Type ON Plant.Plant_ID = Plant_Sun_Type.Plant_ID 

WHERE Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'East-facing'
OR Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'Any'
AND Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Sand' 
OR Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Any'
AND Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture = 'Well-drained' 
OR Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture = 'Any'
AND Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH = 'Acid'
OR Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH = 'Any'
AND Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Foliage_Colour = 'Green'
AND Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Winter'
OR Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Any'
AND Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Flower_Colour = 'Orange'
AND Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Winter'
OR Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Any'

GROUP BY Plant_ID;
```

I was expecting the query to return only those plants that have a record matching the search criteria, ie. only those plants that can be planted in the season 'Winter' or 'Any', but instead it is returning plants it shouldn't be.

For example: http://gyazo.com/d2ca989fc6def79854a1d9b11e4bc310 - `Plant_ID: 1` contains only one record in the `Plant_Flower_Colour` table - Dark Blue during Spring. Why is it this record has been returned? It's as if the trailing `AND`s and `OR`s are being ignored.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative form for the and/or would be to use IN() clauses, which is easyer to read, easyer to edit and less accident-prone.

```
WHERE Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect IN( 'East-facing' , 'Any' )
AND Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type IN( 'Sand' , 'Any' )
AND Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture IN( 'Well-drained' , 'Any' )
AND Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH IN( 'Acid' , 'Any' )
AND Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Foliage_Colour IN( 'Green' )
AND Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season IN( 'Winter' , 'Any' )
AND Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Flower_Colour IN( 'Orange' )
AND Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season IN( 'Winter' , 'Any' )
```

Comment: +1: For an altogether different approach and one which scales neatly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the IN clause!

Answer (score 3):

I think at minimum you need to include parentheses around your OR criteria:

```
...
WHERE (Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'East-facing'
OR Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'Any')
AND (Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Sand' 
OR Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Any')
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parenthesis to group your where criteria.

```
WHERE 
(Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'East-facing'
OR Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'Any')
AND (Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Sand' 
OR Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Any')...
```

Answer (score 2):

The grouping in your WHERE clause is wrong — and ambiguous to the average reader.  AND binds tighter than OR, so you need to use parentheses to make your intention clear to the DBMS:

```
WHERE (Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'East-facing'
   OR  Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'Any')
  AND (Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Sand' 
   OR  Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Any')
  AND (Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture = 'Well-drained' 
   OR  Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture = 'Any')
  AND (Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH = 'Acid'
   OR  Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH = 'Any')
  AND  Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Foliage_Colour = 'Green'
  AND (Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Winter'
   OR  Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Any')
  AND  Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Flower_Colour = 'Orange'
  AND (Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Winter'
   OR  Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Any')
```

What you wrote was treated as if you had written:

```
WHERE  Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'East-facing'
   OR (Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'Any'
  AND  Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Sand')
   OR (Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Any'
  AND  Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture = 'Well-drained')
   OR (Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture = 'Any'
  AND  Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH = 'Acid')
   OR (Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH = 'Any'
  AND  Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Foliage_Colour = 'Green'
  AND  Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Winter')
   OR (Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Any'
  AND  Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Flower_Colour = 'Orange'
  AND  Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Winter')
   OR  Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Any'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time. I didn't actually know you needed to provide parentheses around the AND and OR clause. Learn something new everyday!

Comment: There are two audiences you need to satisfy when you write your query: the DBMS and the other programmers (such as yourself in 6 months time).  Both need to understand what you wrote.  The DBMS understood what you had written and executed the query you wrote correctly.  The trouble was that what you wrote was not the same as what you intended to write.  Basically, always group the terms you want grouped together, either in parentheses or using an alternative technique such as the IN clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing brackets around the OR comparisons.

```
WHERE (Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'East-facing'
OR Plant_Aspect.Plant_Aspect = 'Any')
AND (Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Sand' 
OR Plant_Soil_Type.Plant_Soil_Type = 'Any')
AND (Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture = 'Well-drained' 
OR Plant_Moisture.Plant_Moisture = 'Any')
AND (Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH = 'Acid'
OR Plant_Soil_PH.Plant_Soil_PH = 'Any')
AND Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Foliage_Colour = 'Green'
AND (Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Winter'
OR Plant_Foliage_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Any')
AND Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Flower_Colour = 'Orange'
AND (Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Winter' OR Plant_Flower_Colour.Plant_Season = 'Any')
```